# Ruby on Rails collection_select complexity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have the following Problem, i Have the following in my customer bill view

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_id,Product.all,:id,:name %>
```

This is getting list of all the products from  "Product" model and giving option to select from it. But i want to select the list of products from the "StoreOpeningStock" model.

I have these in my model

```
class Product< ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :store_opening_stocks
has_many :customer_bills
attr_accessible :name
end


class StoreOpeningStock < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :product_id
belongs_to :product 
end


class CustomerBill < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :product_id
 belongs_to :product
accepts_nested_attributes_for :store_opening_stock
end
```

Can anyone guide me how i can get product name and id from store_opening_stock??? Should i use Helpers??? or is there any other way?? Thanks in advance

I tried using helpers

```
def getting_prod_names
        @sto = StoreOpeningStock.all

          for x in @sto
        [
            ['{x.product.title}', '{x.product_id}']
        ]
    end
    end
```

getting following output

```
<%= f.select :product_id, options_for_select(getting_prod_names) %>
```

[image]

ANy Help?? :)

Comment: What do you mean by the list of products from the "StoreOpeningStock" model?

Comment: @SemyonPerepelitsa- "StoreOpeningStock" model has product_ids and Product class has the Name, i want product_id to get selected From StoreOpeningStock model and names get displayed while collection_select in customer bills..!!

Comment: Can you explain the model relationships you have? In the question you said that StoreOpeningStock has product_id (that is a stock belongs to a product), but here you say it has product_ids (that is a stock has many products). As a side note, please don't overuse punctuation marks, it makes harder to understand what you write.

Comment: @SemyonPerepelitsa - Sorry, and yeah i have edited the question with the association, plz tell me if this is enough or should i make any other association?

Comment: So you have one product associated with one stock. What is the list of products do you want to select from? Why don't all products satisfy you?

Comment: Product class contains all the products available or will be available in stores inventory. its only the products which are there in the stock a customer can select to make a bill.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12906/discussion-between-bharath-and-semyon-perepelitsa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a form the data used to ccreate a `collection_select` isnt limited to the Class your going to create an object for. You could simply do the following:

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_id,StoreOpeningStock.all,:product_id ,:name %>
```

This should to it for you,...

add this to your `StoreOpeningStock` class:

```
def name
    return self.product.name unless self.product.nil?
    ""
end
```

Comment: i am getting undefined method `name`...!!

Comment: Thanks lot bro +1 for ur answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to clarify the relationship between your models...

But just to give you an idea. You can define the collection of products you want to display in your `controller`, inside the `action` related to the view (where you are displaying the collection).

Controller:

```
@products= #here you should call all products you want
```

Then, your collection of products can be displayed like:

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, @products,:id,:name %>
```

**EDIT**

You need to revise the relationship between your models. A `product` has many `customer_bills`, but are you sure that each `customer_bill` belongs to a single `product`?
I think you have a many-to-many relationship, as a `customer_bill` can also have many `products`.
If I understand it right, the solution is to create a `ProductLine` model between this many-to-many relationship.

Also, what is the difference between `Product` and `StoreOpeningStock`? What attributes have you included in the `StoreOpeningStock`?
If you have created this model only to show the availability of products, why don't you add an attribute in the `Product` model, for example a boolean column called `availability`.

Comment: Kool Thanks for advice. now m able to get the product but not able to display it properly, m getting the error shown in the question screen shot- instead of helper used a controller.

Comment: Wow, this is has given me a clear understanding about the relationships and how i should use them, for future references. Thanks  buddy. :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to find all products that have a StoreOpeningStock.
This is solely a model concern and have nothing to do with helpers.

```
class Product
  # Find all products that have a StoreOpeningStock
  def self.in_stock
    find(StoreOpeningStock.product_ids)
  end
end

class StoreOpeningStock
  # Collect all product ids from stocks
  def self.product_ids
    uniq.pluck(:product_id)
  end
end
```

Now you can use Product.in_stock instead of Product.all to have the only ones in stock.

Comment: Thanks Semyon but the `pluck` and `uniq` is little confusing can u tell me any documentation or blog where i can go through these ?:)

Comment: The official Rails documentation [website](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) is pretty good, just type in there "pluck". This `uniq.pluck(:product_id)` is basically an SQL equivalent of `map(&:product_id).uniq` for Ruby's Arrays. In other words it collects all product ids from the table records.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a scope to your products model:

```
class Product< ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :store_opening_stocks
    has_many :customer_bills
    attr_accessible :name

    scope :having_store_opening_stocks, :joins => : store_opening_stocks, :select => 'distinct product.*', :conditions => 'store_opening_stocks.product > 0'
end
```

Then you can use Product.all.having_store_opening_stocks to select only products with such stocks, for example:

```
<%= f.select :product_id, Product.having_store_opening_stocks.map { |product| [product.name, product.id] } %>
```

Comment: This is simple and clean...Thank you Chris :)
 i am getting this error undefined method `having_store_opening_stocks' for #<Array:0x3da3e98>

Comment: You should remove `all` from `Product.all.having_store_opening_stocks`